# Can we Encrypt data with private key in angular and Decrypt data with public key in PHP using RSA Encryption?

Tags: javascript, php, angular, codeigniter-3, angular-fullstack

i'm trying to Encrypt data in using RSA Public Key in angular and Decrypt data with public key In   php. i'm trying to Encrypt with JsEncrypt library in angular and Decrypt in Php Using

```
:openssl_public_decrypt($signature, $decrypted, $publicKey, OPENSSL_PKCS1_PADDING);
```

I need to resolve encryption and Decryption  between Angular and Php.

Please see:

**ANGULAR CODE**

```
enc(data: any){  this.$encrypt.setPrivateKey(`dummyprivakey`);
        let ndata = this.$encrypt.encrypt(data);
    console.log("encrypt data ", ndata)
       return ndata
}
```

**PHP CODE :**

```
    openssl_public_decrypt ($encrypted, $decrypted , $publickey); 
       var_dump($decrypted);
```

I'm unable decode the data.

Comment: You could, but why? If it's going between Angular and PHP then it must be going from a browser to a server via a HTTP request. So you can just make sure the request is sent using HTTPS - then it's already secure in transit (because everything which is sent via HTTPS is transferred within an encrypted connection).

Comment: yes, but i need to encrypt the Password in Angular side and decrypt data in php side 
 but we have to encrypt data with **Private Key** and Decrypt data with **Public key**

Comment: Yes, exactly you would have to encrypt with the private key, which then again you wouldn't want to expose to the "world" by having it in the browser. What is the point of this?

Comment: Please see:
**ANGULAR CODE**

  enc(data: any){  this.$encrypt.setPrivateKey(`dummyprivakey`);
  let ndata = this.$encrypt.encrypt(data);
    console.log("encrypt data ", ndata)
       return ndata
  }

**PHP CODE :**
    openssl_public_decrypt ($encrypted, $decrypted , $publickey); 
       var_dump($decrypted);

** i'm unable decode the Data **
please help me out

Comment: `i need to encrypt the Password in Angular side and decrypt data in php side`...do you? Why? What problem is that solving? Like I said, if you transmit the password to PHP via HTTPS then it's **already secure**.

Comment: Encrypting the password in the frontend necessarily means exposing the private key. I'm sure you see why this is a problem.

Comment: `we have to encrypt data with Private Key and Decrypt data with Public key`...actually with RSA you can do it the other way round, too - https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/9957/can-i-use-a-private-key-as-a-public-key-and-vice-versa . But it's really irrelevant in this scenario - as I've said twice now, HTTPS has already implemented your requirement for you.

Comment: Anyway regardless of whether this is a useful task or not, we can't answer the specific question because we don't know what "I'm unable decode the data" actually means in practice, or what debugging you've done. Are you getting an error? Unexpected result? What investigations have you carried out?

Answer (score 2):

Actually this is possible - of course -. The question is: Why would you?

You - and you should always - send your request via HTTPS which means it's secured and encrypted.

So it's unnecessary work for the browser and the PHP code.

Comment: What about a man-in-the-middle attack, when the end-user is connected to a non secure WIFI?

Comment: Please clarify how could an attacker decrypt my encrypted SSL data without the public key?

Comment: Well, thanks to your question I had deeply investigate HTTPS/SSL mechanism/flow and I should say I was wrong in my comment.

Comment: There is one way you can be right: When the user explicitly allows an untrusted SSL (can be a TLS proxy in a business enviroment for example). TLS proxy is kind of a MITM attack.

Answer (score 0):

Look into https://github.com/phpseclib/phpseclib for PHP.

And https://www.npmjs.com/package/encrypt-rsa for angular.

SSL and SSL pinning is great, but there's always a workaround using MITM attacks, and root certificates to bypass SSL pinning.

When **encrypting**, you use a **public key**, and when **decrypting** you use a **private key**, if your front-end does not need to decrypt then make sure to not include the private key in your app as there's always ways to inspect variables in runtime and that would invalidate your entire implementation.

You can always generate more public keys using the private key, so the other way will also invalidate your entire implementation.

If you are looking to transmit data securely, I recommend looking at solutions such as JWE+JWS.

Below are examples using phpseclib for php and encrypt-rsa for angular

For Encrypting in Angular:

```
const encryptedText = encryptRsa.encryptStringWithRsaPublicKey({ 
  text: 'hello world',   
  publicKey,
});
console.log(encryptedText);
```

For decrypting in PHP:

```
$rsa = new Crypt_RSA();
$rsa->loadKey(file_get_contents('private.key')); // private key

echo $rsa->decrypt($encryptedText);
```

Comment: Please share more details, like actual code involved. Don't just post links to external ressources

Comment: @NicoHaase You are absolutely right,  added some examples